# How to translate ids to objects in ng-option angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive, ng-options, angularjs-select

I have array of ids and I need to use this array as source of my ng-option directive inside of select. I certainly could find objects with corresponding id in my collection and create an array of objects to use it instead of array of ids but I wonder is there a way of doing it dynamicaly somehow? Like setting a function as source of ng-option?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to avoid intermediate array of objects.

Comment: With the help of filters. I can post meta example or I could base a demo on your code, if you posed one.

Comment: I don't have  a code example, so could post meta example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the help of filtering by id inside ngOptions directive expression:

```js
angular.module('demo', []).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.ids = [1, 4];
    $scope.objects = [
        {id: 1, name: 'One'},
        {id: 2, name: 'Two'},
        {id: 4, name: 'Four'}
    ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <pre>{{objects}}</pre>
    <pre>{{ids}}</pre>

    <select ng-model="model" 
            ng-options="id as (objects | filter:{id: id})[0].name for id in ids">
    </select>

    {{model}}

</div>
```